# How do I migrate nashorn code in Java 12?

Tags: java, nashorn

I have a legacy app that I am trying to convert from JDK8 to JDK12. One of the places I am having trouble is with the following code...

```
import jdk.nashorn.internal.ir.annotations.Immutable;

import java.util.Base64;

@Immutable // <-here
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public final class Application {
    ....
}
```

When I try to build with IntelliJ I get...

> Error:(6, 43) java: package jdk.nashorn.internal.ir.annotations does not exist
>
> Error:(10, 2) java: cannot find symbol
>    symbol: class Immutable

The code is not easy to follow and I am not sure what this is being used for, but a quick Google search suggests it allows Java to run ES5. It also seems to be deprecated and will be removed soon. Finally it is ES5 and not ESNext so I would like to use something a bit newer.

1. What is this being used for (my guess is JSON serialization but why not use GSON or Jackson?)
2. What can I replace it with that will be Java 12+ compatible?

If I remove it the following test fails...

```
@Test
public void equalsTest() {
    EqualsVerifier.forClass(EvaluationResult.class).verify();
}
```

With the following error message...

```
[ERROR]   EvaluationResultTest.equalsTest:42 Mutability: equals depends on mutable field id.
For more information, go to: http://www.jqno.nl/equalsverifier/errormessages
```

Comment: What happens if you simply remove the import and the [annotation](https://github.com/JetBrains/jdk8u_nashorn/blob/master/src/jdk/nashorn/internal/ir/annotations/Immutable.java)? It's just a tagging annotation, it doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: A test breaks I can post the result one sec.

Comment: @DavidConrad Added more info thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A search for [EqualsVerifier](https://jqno.nl/equalsverifier/) turned up this documentation about its concept of [immutability](https://jqno.nl/equalsverifier/manual/immutability/).

> If you can’t make the fields final, but you’re absolutely certain that the class is immutable, you can add an `@Immutable` annotation to the class. It doesn’t matter where the annotation comes from; you can even write one yourself, as long as it’s called `Immutable`.

So it appears the Nashorn `@Immutable` annotation was only being used for convenience, and any annotation of the same name would do as well, even one defined in your own project:

```
package my.legacy.project.annotations;

/**
 * Tag for classes that are immutable.
 */
public @interface Immutable {
    //empty
}
```

Alternatively, if you can make all the fields of `EvaluationResult` and the fields of all the objects it contains `final`, the documentation indicates the annotation will not be needed, but you may not be able to make `Application` immutable if it needs to be used with JSON, depending on the JSON library used.